# Redirecting domain and subdomain from http to https

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all http requests for my domain and subdomains to https. For example http://example.com should go to https://example.com and http://subdomain1.example.com should go to https://subdomain1.example.com, etc.

I have written this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com$1 [R=302,L]
```

This code is only redirecting the subdomains but it is not redirecting the domain. What changes should I do the above code that it start routing for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to redirect your domains to `https` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```